# htmlにて画像がでないです。どこかおかしいのでしょうか。

Tags: html

以下がソースですが、画像の箇所にミスがあるようですが、わからないです。
どなたか助けて頂けないでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。

以下ソース

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@page{
margin:0;
padding:0;
size:290px 130px;
}
body {
font-family: "メイリオ", Meiryo, "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", Osaka, sans-serif;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
table,
td {
border-collapse: collapse;
mso-table-lspace: 0;
mso-table-rspace: 0;
border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
word-break:break-all;
}
a {
text-decoration: underline;
}
body, table, td, a {
-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
}
img {
border: 0 none;
height: auto;
line-height: 1;
outline: none;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
}
a img {
border: 0 none;
text-decoration: none;
}
span {
display: inline;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100% !important; max-width:306px; padding: 0 0 10px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;font-size: 0;">
<tr>
<td width="306" valign="top" style="width: 306px">

<div style="width: 100%; min-width: 300px; max-width: 306px;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;" class="col2_column">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0 10px 10px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="60" align="left" valign="top"><span style="display: block; border: 1px solid #cccccc;"><a href="" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;"><img valign="middle" src="{{ img_url }}" width="62" height="62" alt="" style="max-width: 100%;"></a></span></td>
<td width="*" align="left" valign="top" style="padding-left: 10px;">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="*" align="left" valign="middle" style="font-family: 'メイリオ', Meiryo, 'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック', 'ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro', Osaka, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height: 22px;"><a href="######" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;color: #000000;">{{ title | truncate(70, True, "...") }}</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left" style="padding: 0 0 0;font-family: 'メイリオ', Meiryo, 'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック', 'ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3', 'Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro', Osaka, sans-serif;color: #000000;font-size: 14px;font-weight: bold;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:24px;">{{ price_string }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ソースコードは極力スタック・オーバーフロー内に貼り付けてください。編集時にソース部分を選択して`{}`を押せばきれいにハイライトされます。

Answer (score 3):

`{{ img_url }}`とあるので、JSXなどの言語のチュートリアルを参考にしているのかもしれません。
そこの部分をファイルパスに置き換えて下さい。
例: HTMLと同じフォルダ内のhoge.pngなら `src="./hoge.png"`
HTMLがあるフォルダ内のimgフォルダにあるfuga.pngなら`src="./img/fuga.png"`